# Getting stuck installing OpenGrm NGram as part of OpenFST

Tags: macos, openfst

I'm trying to install [OpenGrm NGram](http://openfst.cs.nyu.edu/twiki/bin/view/GRM/NGramDownload) on my Mac, but I'm getting stuck while running `make`. Specifically, the process gets hung on the following command:

```
libtool: compile:  g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I./../include -I/usr/local/include/
-std=c++11 -MT hist-arc.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/hist-arc.Tpo -c hist-arc.cc
-fno-common -DPIC -o .libs/hist-arc.o
```

I already have OpenFST and Thrax installed.

Comment: It just hangs?  No error messages or anything?